# Python requests library

Tags: python, installation

I am not all that familiar with Python, but I am trying to write a simple script to scrape NYTimes articles.

I started using `urllib2` and kept getting 403 errors and have no idea what header configuration I can try. So I thought perhaps using the `requests` library would be better.

I installed it with the usual: `python setup.py install`.  Does the code have to be anywhere in particular? I have it in a temp directory and assume it will install things in the right place in my python33 installation.

When I try: `import requests` I get, among other things: `ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3.util'`

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like `urllib3` was not installed. If you have `pip` installed, just do `pip install requests`. That should install `requests` along with its dependencies.

Comment: Ok... pip works now (updated by class path). When I ran pip install requests, it seemed to work: C:\code\project\kennethreitz-requests-142b26e>pip install requests Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in c:\python3 3\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py3.3.egg Cleaning up... But I am still getting the original problem: no module named 'requests.packages.urllib3.util'

Comment: Was using python33, decided to install 34; changed path/classpath; everything is fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your errors are most likely because `requests` requires additional libraries.

Try installing it with

```
pip install requests
```

Take a look at :

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/

Comment: Ok... I did not have pip, so I installed that, but any attempt to use pip does not work.  In python: >>> pip install requests
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `pip` should be run from the command line, not from inside the python interpreter.

Comment: Then I get: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Assuming you are using Windows, check to see if C:\python_version_here\Scripts is in your class path or follow http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: Ok... pip works now (updated by class path).  When I ran pip install requests, it seemed to work: C:\code\project\kennethreitz-requests-142b26e>pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in c:\python3
3\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py3.3.egg
Cleaning up... But I am still getting the original problem: no module named 'requests.packages.urllib3.util'.